# remove blank lines, spaces , paragraph marks from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having text file sample data is as follows

```
 E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER FUNDS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Payee Name:                                                   AAA CHS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

   Nickname:                                                     AAA CHS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

   Credit Account No::                                           AAAA0000006666                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Remarks:                                                      4869                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

   Debit Account:                                                99999999999999                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Date:                                                         05 May '20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

   Amount:                                                       INR 4,869.00         (Rupees     Four Thousand Eight Hundred Sixty  Nine  and Zero Paisa only)
```

If I see this file in word ( File --> Options --> Display -> Always showing formatting masks on screen and select it ALL options it is showing following )

```
 ....E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER Of Funds...................................................................Payee Name...................
.....................................................................................................
AAA CHS.........................................................AAA CHS...........................Nickname ....etc 

Here (...) means spaces and in between lines it also shows paragraph symbols(¶) pillow cover and also at the end of file it is showing 3 paragraph symbols.
```

I want output like ( removing blank spaces and paragraph symbols)

```
E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER FUNDS
Payee Name:                                                   AAA CHS 
Nickname:                                                     AAA CHS 
Credit Account No::                                           AAAA0000006666
...
...
```

I tried something like following

```
file=open("c:\\temp1\\tt1.txt", "r+")
for line in file.readlines():
    print(line.strip())
file.close()
```

it is not working. Pl note that I do not want to remove spaces in between words I want to remove spaces / special characters between the lines.

Secondly though it is not requirement can I put only one space before and after ":" or "::"  e.g.

```
E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER FUNDS
Payee Name : AAA CHS 
Nickname : AAA CHS 
Credit Account No :: AAAA0000006666
```

...etc

Answer (score 0):

Use this convenience function:

```py
import re
def text_processor(s):
    # s = your text
    return '\n'.join(str.split(re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', re.sub('\n\n', '|\n', s.replace('::',':'))), '|')).replace(':', ' :')
```

**Example**:

```py
# s = your text
# assuming you are reading in from a file: 'data.txt'
# with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
#    s = f.read()
print(text_processor(s))
```

**Output**:

```
E-RECEIPT FOR TRANSFER FUNDS 
 Payee Name : AAA CHS 
 Nickname : AAA CHS 
 Credit Account No : AAAA0000006666 
 Remarks : 4869 
 Debit Account : 99999999999999 
 Date : 05 May '20 
 Amount : INR 4,869.00 (Rupees Four Thousand Eight Hundred Sixty Nine and Zero Paisa only)
```

### Dummy Data

```
s = """
E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER FUNDS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Payee Name:                                                   AAA CHS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

   Nickname:                                                     AAA CHS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

   Credit Account No::                                           AAAA0000006666                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Remarks:                                                      4869                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

   Debit Account:                                                99999999999999                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   Date:                                                         05 May '20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

   Amount:                                                       INR 4,869.00         (Rupees     Four Thousand Eight Hundred Sixty  Nine  and Zero Paisa only) 
"""

print(s)
```

### Open Docx file from Python

Reference: [source](http://theautomatic.net/2019/10/14/how-to-read-word-documents-with-python/)

```py
import docx2txt

# read in word file
s = docx2txt.process("data.docx")

# Copy pasting the dummy data into a docx file
# and trying to read and correcting the data 
# requires the following fix

print(text_processor(s).replace(' \n \n ', '\n'))
```

Comment: @Parag this should give you what you asked for.

Comment: @Cyperhex thanks a lot for detail explanation and help, but it is still not working. I have uploaded sample input ile in google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wqtS8M5KdRFemvRbG-JjMCs64liQlKSZ/view?usp=sharing, pl check

Comment: Pl download this file and open in word, then go to options - display and select ALL in format settings, to see what characters are appearing.

Comment: First try the solution with the **Dummy Data** section as `s` and then run `text_processor(s)`. This should work for you at least.

Comment: @Parag I will prefer not to download any file. Your problem mainly asks for how to remove those spaces and empty lines. The solution I have posted takes care of that. Please check and let me know.

Comment: it is working on Dummy data perfectly fine in jupyter notebook. even a writing to file is working perfectly fine also. But it is not working with input file where i am doing a testing. Pl suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213157/discussion-between-cypherx-and-parag).

Comment: I tried s1=text_processor(s) where s is a dummy data. s = """
E-RECEIPT FOR  TRANSFER FUNDS ...........................................................""" and with open("c:\\temp1\\o1.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(s1)